# Wrap Phalcon flash messages in HTML element

Tags: phalcon

Is there a possibility to wrap flash messages in an element? I want to have no html element at all when there are no messages and have an extra div containing all messages if there is any message.

It would be enough if I could at least get information whether there are any flash messages and then code it myself, but it seems to me that neither Phalcon\Flash\Direct nor Phalcon\Flash\Session allow you to access current message count or wrap messages in your own html element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have ended with following code. I basically had to generate output myself.

```
<?php
    $messages = $this->flashSession->getMessages();
    if ( count($messages) > 0) {
?>
    <div class="basic-bg">
        <div class="main-column">
            <div class="flash-messages">
                <?php 
                foreach ($messages as $messageType => $messageArray) {
                    foreach ($messageArray as $message) {
                        echo "<div class=\"flash-$messageType\">$message</div>";
                    }
                }
                ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Just configure your flash service to just output the message:

```
$this->flash->setAutomaticHtml(false);
```

Also, when outputting a message, it's automatically echoed.
If you want to just return a string without echoing it to the output buffer use:

```
$this->flash->setImplicitFlush(false);
```

These methods aren't in the [**main documentation page**](http://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/flash.html), but you should always look at the [**class reference**](http://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/api/Phalcon_Flash_Session.html) too, you might find very usefull information there :)

#### EDIT

To return **only messages** you use `setAutomaticHtml` to false, `setImplicitFlush` has nothing to do with it. Also to know if a message exists use something like this:

```
$this->flashSession->has('error');
```

Comment: Thank you very much for trying to help me, but still no success. setImplicitFlush(false) will cause output() function to not output anything, but it doesn't return any messages neither. How can I know if there are any messages before I output them? I tried calling getMessages function to check it there are any existing messages, but it seems to flush messages array and output won't work as well.

Comment: it says "has" is an undefined method, this was actually my first guess

Comment: @lot my bad, `has` is only implemented for `flashSession` since there's no point for using it for direct flashes (when you flash a message directly it isn't stored).

Comment: I am actually using flashSession, it isn't implemented there either :-)

Comment: @lot strange, here works fine http://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/api/Phalcon_Flash_Session.html

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old thread, but how about implementing an extended class to make sure your message string is still correctly escaped?

This is the class I've used to implement Bootstrap 3 dismissable messages:

```
<?php
namespace Ext;
/**
 * Extension to Phalcon Framework to implement Bootstrap 3 dismissable messages.
 * Pass mappings of phalcon to bootstrap classes to construct
 * @link https://docs.phalconphp.com/uk/latest/reference/flash.html Phalcon flash docs
 * @author Kevin Andrews <kevin@zvps.uk>
 */
class FlashBootstrap extends \Phalcon\Flash\Session
{
    /**
     * Correctly escapes the message while building a Bootstrap 3
     * compatible dismissable message with surrounding html.
     * @param string $type
     * @param string $message
     * @return void
     */
    public function message($type, $message)
    {
        $bootstrapCssClass = $this->_cssClasses[$type];
        $errorType = ucfirst($type);
        $bootstrapMessage = "<div class=\"alert alert-{$bootstrapCssClass} alert-dismissible\" role=\"alert\"><button type=\"button\" class=\"close\" data-dismiss=\"alert\" aria-label=\"Close\"><span aria-hidden=\"true\">&times;</span></button><strong>{$errorType}:</strong> {$this->getEscaperService()->escapeHtml($message)}</div>";
        parent::message($type, $bootstrapMessage);
    }
}
```

Also for completeness the initialisation for DI:

```
 <?php
        $di->set('flash', function() {
            $bootstrapFlash = new Ext\FlashBootstrap(array(
                'error' => 'alert alert-danger alert-dismissible',
                'success' => 'alert alert-success alert-dismissible',
                'notice' => 'alert alert-info alert-dismissible',
                'warning' => 'alert alert-dismissible',
            ));
            $bootstrapFlash->setAutoescape(false);
            $bootstrapFlash->setAutomaticHtml(false);
            return $bootstrapFlash;
        });
```

This also has the advantage that the ->success() ->error() ->notice() and ->warning() helper methods will all go through this code and produce nicely formatted messages wrapped in the desired HTML.

Answer (score 0):

```
{% if flash.has('notice')==true OR flash.has('success') %}
    {% for notif in flash.getMessages('success') %}
        <div class="notif_global success">
            <div class="notif_global-title">Успешно</div>
            <div class="notif_global-content">{{ notif }}</div>
            <div class="notif_global-close ico_close"></div>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
    {% for notif in flash.getMessages('notice') %}
        <div class="notif_global success">
            <div class="notif_global-title">Сообщение</div>
            <div class="notif_global-content">{{ notif }}</div>
            <div class="notif_global-close ico_close"></div>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
{% if flash.has('warning')==true OR flash.has('error') %}
    {% for notif in flash.getMessages('warning') %}
        <div class="notif_global error">
            <div class="notif_global-title">Предупреждение</div>
            <div class="notif_global-content">{{ notif }}</div>
            <div class="notif_global-close ico_close"></div>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
    {% for notif in flash.getMessages('error') %}
        <div class="notif_global error">
            <div class="notif_global-title">Ошибка</div>
            <div class="notif_global-content">{{ notif }}</div>
            <div class="notif_global-close ico_close"></div>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```